# SQL query : Insert DIFFERENCE OF TIME from 2 different tables to a 3rd table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, insert-update

```
INSERT INTO order_time( link, time )
SELECT link, CAST
(
( 
(
   SELECT FIRST (t.time AS dtime)
   FROM delivery_time t, quantity q
   WHERE t.link = q.link
) - 
(
    SELECT FIRST (orderTime)
    FROM delivery_time t, menu m, quantity q
    WHERE t.link = q.link
    AND t.menuId = m.menuId
)
) AS time( 0 )
)
FROM quantity where 1
```

I am getting error message.

quantity comprises of (link,qty); link is unique and int

order_time: (link,time) ; link is unique and int, time is of datatype time

delivery_time: (link,menuId,time); for a menuId(int), there are different time (datatype time) and for a set of some different time for a menuId there is link; so menuId & time combination is unique:

```
menuId    time    link
1       12:00:00   1
1       12:10:00   1
1       14:00:00   2
1       14:10:00   2
1       14:20:00   2
2       12:00:00   3
2       12:10:00   3
2       12:20:00   3
2       14:00:00   4
2       14:10:00   4
2       15:00:00   5
```

& menu: (menuId, orderTime); menuId is unique & orderTime is in datatype time.

My need is: creating a table order_time (link,time) where link is unique & taken from quantity. here time is the difference of first instance of time corresponding to that link in delivery_time & orderTime from menu table that corresponds to menuId as in delivery_time table.

```
ERROR:MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(t.time AS dtime)
   FROM delivery_time t, quantity q
   WHERE t.link = q.link' at line 6
```

Comment: Please take some time to use the formatting features next time. When you ask a question there is a preview below the box you type in, and there are buttons and help available to make your code look readable.

Comment: I have pressed the `{}` button a couple of times for you, please review the rest and try to make it clear so a person looking at this might actually be able to help you

Comment: Please don't use such words like "*plz help, its urgent*" on this site.

Comment: @Rajdeep: you can also use http://sqlfiddle.com/ if you want more clarity to what you wanted to achieve

Comment: well, i cud have just explained the problem without the code, if i wanted spoon feeding! and I'm new to this website, thought there were more friendly people than rude jerks...

Comment: There's an introduction for new users. There's also tons of questions that have been formatted. What you did was pasting an error you got expecting other people to fix something that you're probably being paid for. It seems to me that there's this notion of "go to stackoverflow.com, there are fanatics who are dying to help you out all day long for free, you don't even have to try to fix your errors or learn how to code". Sadly, the rude jerk is no one but yourself by not respecting peer coders who are here to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO order_time( link, time )
SELECT link, CAST
    (
        ( 
            (
            SELECT MIN(t.time)
            FROM delivery_time t
                INNER JOIN quantity q ON
                    t.link = q.link
            ) - 
            (
            SELECT MIN(orderTime)
            FROM delivery_time t
                INNER JOIN menu m ON
                    t.menuId = m.menuId
                INNER JOIN quantity q ON
                    t.link = q.link
            )
        ) AS time(0)
    )
FROM quantity
where 1 = 1
```